# SQL Join from value that only exists in right table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a JOIN of two tables:

Table 1

```
DCID  
Scores  
Grade
```

Table 2

```
DCID  
lastFirst  
address  
phone
```

I want to join the lastFirst from Table 2 to Table 1 to get:

```
DCID  
lastFirst  
Scores  
Grade
```

Peter

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a simple `join`

```
select t1.DCID, t2.lastFirst, t1.Scores, t1.Grade 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.DCID = t2.DCID
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works--the column headers are correct but there is no data below.  I must be missing something...

Answer (score -1):

SELECT a.DCID, Scores, Grade, b.lastFirst FROM T1 as a, T2 as b WHERE a.DCID = b.DCID;